Finding the right length and strength of gas spring to lift cabinet door
I am building a cabinet that have a swing door that opens upwards. Door size is 2343mm wide x 1198 height x 19mm thick. Door to swing upwards 110 degree from closed position. Door weight is 22kg. Ideally gas spring shall not protrude more than 100 to prevent head bumping onto it when door is opened. Please advise gas spring,

Force
Length
Mounting position if what I want is not feasible.



looks like your pivot positions will always cause the door to open. The closed position needs to go just over centre so the piston pressure holds the door closed - only needs to go 5mm past the centre line.

Thank u for the reply. Are you refering to the cabinet or the door?

try drawing the closed position and think about what happens.

Gas Spring Calculator

Plywood door is heavy and you are going to lift it with gas struts which push more sideways than upwards in the open position. Most of the strut compression force only stresses the materials and demands much more robust parts than versions where the struts push more upwards.
Assuming the wanted opening angle (2 different values are given in the question) is 20 degrees above horizontal this case can be (theoretically) solved by inserting 2 struts which have cylinder outer diameter 19 millimeters and max length = 500 millimeters
When the door is full open each strut must produce 750 newtons. The struts are compressed in the full open position 5 mm shorter from their max length. That's the common force spec compression. The struts are shortest when the door is nearly closed. Then the piston is pushed in 148 millimeters, so even 150 mm stroke length is enough. 200 millimeter stroke lengths are generally available for 500 mm long struts.
The next image (drawn without any proportions) shows the mounting ideas:

The upper joint of the strut is placed 50 mm out of the door hinge plane surface and distance C along the surface is 450 millimeters.
The 50 mm protrusion from the door is there to make possible the struts to push the door actively (a couple of newton meters torque) towards the closed position when the door position angle alpha is -90 degrees. 10 mm would be enough to make the strut to have the needed room and that's used at the other end.
Force 750 newtons plus some safety margin at the strut joints needs special care - you surely do not want the struts to break themselves free. Quite a challenge with wooden door and cabin, I'd say!
How did I calculate it? It's an elementary geometry and torque problem. I wrote the formulas to a spreadsheet.I can insert the formulas if someone wants to open Pandora's Box.
One can check lengths and angles even by drawing. Also the axial strut force can be divided by drawing to 2 perpendicular components to see which percentage of the force actually lifts the door. Both drawings are in the next image for the door position angle +20 degrees over horizontal:

The upper half shows the strut length L. The lower half shows the finding of the torque when the total compression force of the struts is 1500 newtons. A 2 dimensional CAD program would be the perfect drawing tool, but these are drawn in Inkscape. Calculator is needed only for scaling and multiplying. Actually even the torque could be presented as surface area, but that's not handy.
My calculations skipped all material strength subjects and the dynamics, for example how fast the door actually opens if it's pulled manually out of the "keep closed" region. Fortunately practical struts have also effective braking property which very likely prevents the door knocking out the door user.
Then a couple of other things:
In my 1st drawing the struts are reversed when compared to your drawing. I guessed the door is most of the time closed. The struts keep their gas pressure longer if the cylinder is upwards most of the time.
If the cabin isn't especially deep, it happens to be light and empty and it's not fastened to the building some stability problems can occur. Placing the hinge differently could fix it. In addition it could allow to have struts which lift more upwards than push sideways and do it without creating the head banging trap that you wanted to avoid.

